# How to rewrite this POST curl script in python?

Tags: php, python, post, curl

I'm going to rewrite this POST request in python:

```
<?php
// Set these variables
$networkid = ""; // In your HasOffers system at Support -> API
$apikey = ""; // In your HasOffers system at Support -> API
$offerid = "0"; // Specify an offer ID to add the creative to
$creativetype = "image banner"; // Types: file, image banner, flash banner, email creative, offer thumbnail, text ad, html ad, hidden
$filename = "banner_728x90.gif"; // File name; no spaces, and file must be in same directory as this script
$display = $filename; // Or change this to the "display name" for this creative

// Don't change anything below here
$creativetype = urlencode($creativetype);
$display = urlencode($display);
$fields[$filename] = "@{$filename}";
$url = "http://api.hasoffers.com/v3/OfferFile.json?Method=create&NetworkToken={$apikey}&NetworkId={$networkid}&data[offer_id]={$offerid}&data[type]={$creativetype}&data[display]={$display}&return_object=1";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r(json_decode($resp, true)); // Final output; remove or change this if you want
?>
```

As I know, in pycurl the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS attribute is absent. What can I use instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `requests` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many python libraries that can be used:

http.client

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html

requests

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/

the commands are pretty straightforwards:

using http.client:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
res = conn.getresponse()
print(res.status, res.reason)
200 OK
```

or requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
print r.json
```

Using HTTP client, a simple POST request may be done as follows:

```
connect = http.client.HTTPSConnection("base_url")
connect.request('POST', '/rest/api/'+ you_can_add_variables+ '/users?userEmail=' + another_variable, headers=headers)
```

Using requests:

```
import json
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

the documentation provided above should not prove difficult to understand

Comment: could you give an example for post request, using these libraries? Setting for two parameters is enogh.